# Python cx_freeze issue with resources

Tags: python, python-3.3, cx-freeze

I am using the `cx_freeze` module to create an installer and executable. This seems to work fine, but upon running the executable I get the following error and traceback.

```
D:\>"app.exe"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 421, in get_provider
    module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]
KeyError: 'resources.images'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1148, in resource_filename
    return get_provider(package_or_requirement).get_resource_filename(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 423, in get_provider
    __import__(moduleOrReq)
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_and_load
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1514, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_and_load
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1531, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'resources'
```

This is strange because I get no such error when running the script through Python. (To be specific, Shift-F10 on PyCharm.)

This is the only script I wrote in the traceback:

```
main.py

from tkinter import Tk
from client import Client
from pkg_resources import resource_filename

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("MyApp")
root.wm_iconbitmap(root, resource_filename('resources.images', 'eternal_logo.ico'))
root.wm_iconbitmap()
client = Client(root)
root.mainloop()
```

My setup.py looks like:

```
setup.py

from setuptools import find_packages
from pkg_resources import resource_filename
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name='MyApp',
    version='0.3-alpha',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={'': ['*.png', '*.gif', '*.ico']},
    executables=[
        Executable(
            "main.py",
            icon=resource_filename('resources.images', 'eternal_logo.ico'),
            targetName="app.exe"
        )
    ]
)
```

And lastly my file structure (abbreviated) looks like:

```
MyApp/
  bin/
  build/
  client/
    __init__.py
    ..
  dist/
  docs/
  preferences/
    __init__.py
    ..
  resources/
    __init__.py
    images/
      __init__.py
  main.py
  setup.py
  __init__.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a while ago but since I am having a similar issue again I was brought back to this.

I believe what fixed this was adding the following `build_exe_options` to `setup.py`:

```
build_exe_options = {
    "include_files": [
        ('resources', 'resources'),
        ('config.ini', 'config.ini')
    ]
}
```